# adding action event to button in google maps sdk in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my application i created a button on the google maps mapview as a subview. now how to add click event to that button. That button is visible in app but not visible in nib file. how to add the event

Comment: i got the answer. sorry for posting without proper search

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Implement :

```
-(IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)sender
     {
         // button cliked...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

just try adding target to your button like

```
[button addTarget:yourObject action:@selector(yourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```